# AngularJS: Dynamic URL Prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a large angular app that lives at a URL like so:

```
http://myangularapp.com/app/index.html#/
```

The URL I intend on giving out will need a name injected into the URL as this one site will support multiple users.

So, without modifying any directory structure,  I'd like to do:

```
http://myangularapp.com/app/bob/index.html#/
```

and also:

```
http://myangularapp.com/app/harry/index.html#/
```

All my controllers and functionality would ideally stay the same.

Super stumped on this one!

Comment: You may need to modify the `.htaccess` or setup in the server. it can't be done at the angular app level. Angular route can only modify routes after index.html

Comment: As mohamedrias said, you have to config it in the server? What server are you using for hosting the html files: Apache or IIS?

Comment: I'm using IIS. I'd like to have "harry" or "bob" as a variable I could use. It would seem that adding a querystring variable is the only way to go here

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$routeProvider` service. You can define where urls go, like so.

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/app/foo/bar/what/about/bob', {
        templateUrl: 'app/bob/index.html', <---directory and url don't have to match
        controller: 'bobController'
      }).
      when('/app/harry', { ...
      })
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done via $routeProvider. $routeProvider can only modify routes after `index.html`.  Not the route before

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I would need "bob" to be a variable that I could grab, i.e. if 'http://myangularapp.com/app/sally/index.html#/' was a URL a person invoked, the site would still execute, but would be able grab "sally" from the url. 

Right now, 
http://myangularapp.com/app/index.html#/ works fine, I just wanted to keep my mostly clean URL. It looks like I'll be adding a querystring variable to solve this